# Is there a way to always insert an empty lines between if-else statements and try-catch blocks with clang-format?

Tags: clang-format

I would like to convert

```
if (true) {
    ...
} else {
   ...
}
```

to

```
if (true) {
   ...
}

else {
   ...
}
```

The same for try-catch blocks. I couldn't find anything on that in the clang-format docs.

https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Never seen that, but pretty sure there are styles with the closing brace, else and opening brace each on its own line. That gives you the same total vertical <strike>waste</strike> spacing.

Comment: Hmm can't find anything. It is the only thing I am missing